How can I extract the coordinates from the coastal part of this sf object in R?
Using the rnaturalearth package, I have been able to produce a map of Atlantic like so.
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)

#Load Canada from Natural Earth
canada_dl = ne_countries(scale = 110, country = "Canada")
#Plot Canada, but only the Atlantic Canada bits 
canada_atlantic_only = st_crop(canada_dl, xmin = -70, xmax = -50 , ymin = 41, ymax = 61)

This is what the map itself looks like, and I'm okay with that.

What I would like to do is to start along the coastline of this map, and then extract coordinates along that line. I will be using those coordinates draw other lines to points closer and further offshore, but basically I don't know how to ask R to give me the coordinates of the line which represents the coastline of Atlantic Canada. Is there a way to use rnaturalearth to do that?

I suppose that you are ok with your definition of the Atlantic, but there is a shared border with USA. It's not clear if polylines are wanted, or coordinates of points
With the package sf, st_boundary() is usefull to transform the polygons to polylines. st_difference allow to remove the border with the USA. The first points of the polylines are printed as coordinates , another good solution has been made by L Tyrone.
(I removed some warnings )
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(sf)

library(tidyverse)

#Load Canada from Natural Earth
canada_dl = ne_countries(scale = 110, country = "Canada")
#Plot Canada, but only the Atlantic Canada bits 
canada_atlantic_only = st_crop(canada_dl, xmin = -70, xmax = -50 , ymin = 41, ymax = 61)


# Get USA boundary
us_boundary = ne_countries(scale = 110, country = "United States of America") %>%  st_boundary()

can_boundary  <-canada_dl  %>%  st_boundary()

coast_boundary = st_difference(can_boundary,us_boundary ) %>% 
  st_crop(canada_dl, xmin = -70, xmax = -50 , ymin = 41, ymax = 61)

ggplot() + geom_sf(data =  coast_boundary )



print(coast_boundary %>% st_coordinates() %>% head() )
#>              X        Y L1 L2
#> [1,] -69.59157 61.02989  1  1
#> [2,] -69.62033 60.22125  1  1
#> [3,] -69.28790 58.95736  1  1
#> [4,] -68.37455 58.80106  1  1
#> [5,] -67.64976 58.21206  1  1
#> [6,] -66.20178 58.76731  1  1

Created on 2024-11-01 with reprex v2.1.0

+1 this is really clever. I tried to achieve this using other methods but yours is by far the easiest way. I updated my answer to include a tweaked version of yours that is more generalisable.

This is great and it is what I'm looking for. I tried redoing it via the rnaturalearth coastline dataset, too, but sadly that did not seem to work. Might post further questions later but I want to say thanks for now.

To add on L Tyrone's answer, if you cast to a LINESTRING, re-project to a CRS that isn't Lat/Lon, you can use sf::st_line_sample() to get more granular points than just casting straight from the MULTIPOLYGON to POINT. Here, you'd get a point every 5 km or so. Don't have time to look up a better projection, sorry!
# cast to linestring
line <- canada_atlantic_only |>
    sf::st_geometry() |>
    sf::st_cast("POLYGON") |>
    sf::st_cast("LINESTRING")


# take the lines and cast to pts
pts <- line |>
    # transform to a different CRS
    sf::st_transform(crs = 3395) |>
    # take a point every 5 km
    sf::st_line_sample(density = 1 / 5000) |>
    # back to a sf data.frame
    sf::st_as_sf() |>
    # add an index for land body
    dplyr::mutate(I = dplyr::row_number()) |>
    # transform back to lat/lon
    sf::st_transform(crs = 4326) |>
    # from MULTIPOINT -> POINT
    sf::st_cast("POINT")

# map
mapview::mapview(pts)


+1, this is a really good idea. Added a version of this that incorporates the start/end vertices as well.

This is really helpful, thanks.

Updated
Improved my original approach to incorporate both answers from VinceGreg and sonshine. Original answer at the end.
You can use sf::st_cast() to convert geometry types or sf::st_coordinates() to return a matrix of just the coordinates. Note that the following methods will return warnings which you can safely ignore for your use-case. They are telling you that values from the original geometries will be carried over to each individual part if a feature is split up e.g. if you have area values etc., you will need to re-calculate them again after st_cast().
Option 1:
If you just want vertices of each linestring, here is a generalised version of VinceGreg's answer, which removes internal/country borders. This will work in cases where there may be multiple country borders, and it does not require the neighbouring countries to be defined beforehand.
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Country of interest 
coi <- "Canada"

# Define projected CRS
crs = 3395

# Create cropping sf polygon based on your coordinates, project to crs
bbox <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = -70,
                            ymin = 41,
                            xmax = -50,
                            ymax = 61))) %>%
  st_as_sf(crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(crs)

# Load coi sf
canada_dl <- ne_countries(scale = 110, country = coi)

# Return coi boundary, project
canada_b <- ne_countries(scale = 110) %>%
  st_transform(crs) %>%
  st_boundary()

# Return line vertices
coast_v <- ne_countries(scale = 110) %>%
  st_transform(crs) %>%
  filter(sovereignt != coi) %>%
  st_boundary() %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  st_difference(canada_b, .) %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(canada_dl)) %>%
  st_crop(xmin = -70, xmax = -50 , ymin = 41, ymax = 61) %>%
  st_cast("POINT") %>%
  select()

coast_v
# Simple feature collection with 104 features and 0 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -70 ymin: 43.54523 xmax: -52.6481 ymax: 61.02989
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#                      geometry
# 1  POINT (-69.59157 61.02989)
# 2  POINT (-69.62033 60.22125)
# 3   POINT (-69.2879 58.95736)
# 4  POINT (-68.37455 58.80106)
# 5  POINT (-67.64976 58.21206)
# 6  POINT (-66.20178 58.76731)
# 7  POINT (-65.24517 59.87071)
# 8  POINT (-64.58352 60.33558)
# 9   POINT (-63.80475 59.4426)
# 10 POINT (-62.50236 58.16708)

# Return coordinates only
coast_coords <- st_coordinates(coast_v)

head(coast_coords)
#              X        Y
# [1,] -69.59157 61.02989
# [2,] -69.62033 60.22125
# [3,] -69.28790 58.95736
# [4,] -68.37455 58.80106
# [5,] -67.64976 58.21206
# [6,] -66.20178 58.76731

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = canada_dl) +
  geom_sf(data = coast_v, aes(colour = "Vertices"), size = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "", values = "firebrick") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-70, -50),
           ylim = c(41, 61),
           expand = FALSE)


Option 2:
If you need a more detailed set of coordinates, you can use sf::st_line_sample(). However, sf::st_line_sample() omits the start and end points of a linestring, which may be critical. To this end, these can be generated using st_startpoint() and st_endpoint() from the lwgeom package.
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(lwgeom)
library(ggplot2)

# Country of interest 
coi <- "Canada"

# Define projected CRS
crs = 3395

# Create cropping sf polygon based on your coordinates, project to crs
bbox <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(c(xmin = -70,
                            ymin = 41,
                            xmax = -50,
                            ymax = 61))) %>%
  st_as_sf(crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(crs)

# Load coi sf
canada_dl <- ne_countries(scale = 110, country = coi)

# Return coi boundary, project
canada_b <- ne_countries(scale = 110) %>%
  st_transform(crs) %>%
  st_boundary()

# Return coast linestring
coast_l <- ne_countries(scale = 110) %>%
  filter(sovereignt != coi) %>%
  st_transform(crs) %>%
  st_boundary() %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  st_difference(canada_b, .) %>%
  st_crop(bbox) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

# Return sample points @ approximately 50km intervals
coast_s <- st_line_sample(coast_l, density = 1 / 50000) %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  st_cast("POINT") %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  rename(geometry = x)

# Return start and end points
coast_sp <- st_startpoint(coast_l) %>%
  st_as_sf()
coast_ep <- st_endpoint(coast_l) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Combine start/end points, remove duplicates, combine with sample point
coast_all <- bind_rows(coast_sp, coast_ep) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  st_transform(4326) %>%
  rename(geometry = x) %>%
  bind_rows(coast_s)

coast_all
# Simple feature collection with 281 features and 0 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -70 ymin: 43.56475 xmax: -52.71233 ymax: 61
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#                      geometry
# 1        POINT (-69.59263 61)
# 2        POINT (-70 47.19719)
# 3  POINT (-55.60022 51.31707)
# 4  POINT (-64.51912 49.87304)
# 5  POINT (-64.01486 47.03601)
# 6        POINT (-70 47.70799)
# 7  POINT (-67.13741 45.13753)
# 8  POINT (-69.59657 60.89049)
# 9  POINT (-69.60444 60.67035)
# 10 POINT (-69.61231 60.44868)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = canada_dl) +
  geom_sf(data = coast_all, aes(colour = "Sample/Start/\nEnd Points"),
          size = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "", values = "firebrick") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-70, -50),
           ylim = c(41, 61),
           expand = FALSE)


Original answer
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(sf)

canada_dl = ne_countries(scale = 110, country = "Canada") |>
  st_crop(xmin = -70, xmax = -50 , ymin = 41, ymax = 61) |>
  st_cast("POINT")

canada_dl[,"geometry"]
# Simple feature collection with 114 features and 0 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -70 ymin: 43.54523 xmax: -52.6481 ymax: 61.02989
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# First 10 features:
#   geometry
# 1        POINT (-70 46.69299)
# 2  POINT (-69.99997 46.69307)
# 3  POINT (-69.23722 47.44778)
# 4      POINT (-68.905 47.185)
# 5  POINT (-68.23444 47.35486)
# 6  POINT (-67.79046 47.06636)
# 7  POINT (-67.79134 45.70281)
# 8  POINT (-67.13741 45.13753)
# 9  POINT (-66.02605 45.25931)
# 10 POINT (-64.42549 45.29204)

# If you want just the coordinates
canada_dl = ne_countries(scale = 110, country = "Canada") |>
  st_crop(xmin = -70, xmax = -50 , ymin = 41, ymax = 61) |>
  st_coordinates()

head(canada_dl)
#              X        Y L1 L2 L3
# [1,] -70.00000 46.69299  1  1  1
# [2,] -69.99997 46.69307  1  1  1
# [3,] -69.23722 47.44778  1  1  1
# [4,] -68.90500 47.18500  1  1  1
# [5,] -68.23444 47.35486  1  1  1
# [6,] -67.79046 47.06636  1  1  1

